# Sending Mail And Updating Database in Java web project

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, javabeans

I want to make a *registration* page on which user gives email id and hit *submit* button .

What I want to do when the user hit *submit* button a *random password get generate* and send to his email  ID and further he can login using that password . 
Randomly generated password and email id get stored in my *database (My SQL)* .

I am using this code to send mail . This file is in Login/src/beanmail/SendMailExample.java

```
 package beanmail;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport;

public class SendMailExample {

public static boolean sendMail(String mail, String pass) {
boolean flag=false;
String from = "******@gmail.com";
String to = mail;
String subject = "Your user name and password..";
String message = mail+","+pass;
SendMail sendMail = new SendMail(from, to, subject,message);
sendMail.send();
flag = true;
return flag;
}
}

class SendMail {
private String from;
private String to;
private String subject;
private String text;
public SendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String text){
this.from = from;
this.to = to;
this.subject = subject;
this.text = text;
}

public void send()
{
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
String userid = "*******@gmail.com";
String password = "******";
try
{
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
props.put("mail.smtp.user", userid);
props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
InternetAddress fromAddress = null;
InternetAddress toAddress = null;

try {
fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
} catch (AddressException e) {

e.printStackTrace();
}
message.setFrom(fromAddress);
message.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setText(text);

//SMTPSSLTransport transport =(SMTPSSLTransport)session.getTransport("smtps");

Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
transport.connect(host, userid, password);
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();
} catch (MessagingException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Here I am registered  new user

```
<jsp:useBean id="mal" class="beanmail.SendMailExample"></jsp:useBean>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
String mail = request.getParameter("mail");
double dd = Math.random();
int val = (int)(dd*100000);
String pass = String.valueOf(val);
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java","root","root");
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into login values(?,?)");
    ps.setString(1, mail);
    ps.setString(2, pass);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    if(mal.sendMail(mail,pass))
    {
        out.println("Password is Send to your mail id");
    }

}
catch(Exception e){}

%>

</body>
```

This code i am using to do Authentication.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Driver"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
String mail = request.getParameter("mail");
String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Login","root","root");
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from login");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next())
    {
        if(mail.equals(rs.getString(1))&&pass.equals(rs.getString(2)))
        {
            response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
        }
    }
    out.print("Wrong User name nd Password");
}
catch(Exception e){}
%>
</body>
```

Database is not getting updated & Mail is not able to send . Where i Doing Worng . Image  of my [database](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1688334/) .Using My SQL server 5.5 on Ubuntu 12.04 . I notice somehting on right bottom corner saying readonly.

[image: MySQL data base]

Comment: Have you checked logs? Any exceptions thrown?

Comment: @rootkit007 I checked No Exception Caught .